# Get server side exported crystal report path on client machine using javascript for mail attachment in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

hi below is my javascript code for opening default outlook.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SendAttach() {
        var theApp //Reference to Outlook.Application 
        var theMailItem //Outlook.mailItem
        var attach3 = '<%= Session["MyFilePath"].ToString() %>'
        var recipient
        var subject = "Report Document"
        var msg = "Please Find Attached File \n\n" + "Thanks & Regards \n" + '<%=  Session["USER"].ToString() %>'
        try {
            var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
            var objNS = theApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
            var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0) // value 0 = MailItem

            theMailItem.Subject = (subject);
            theMailItem.Body = (msg);
            theMailItem.Attachments.add(attach3);
            theMailItem.display();
        } catch (err) {
            alert("The following may have cause this error: \n" + "1. The Outlook express 2003 is not installed on the machine.\n" + "2. The msoutl.olb is not availabe at the location " + "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\msoutl.old on client's machine " + "due to bad installation of the office 2003." + "Re-Install office2003 with default settings.\n" + "3. The Initialize and Scripts ActiveX controls not marked as safe is not set to enable.")

        }

    }
</script>
```

in this `<%= Session["MyFilePath"].ToString() %>` is passed by server side code.
`MyFilePath` is path of my file which i am attaching as an attachment in outlook.
this working fine on server side but when i run on client side this file path is not attaching attachment which is on server side.

below is my server side code.

```
reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Boreports/Print_Lpo.rpt"));

Session["Rpt_Name"] = "Local_Purchase_Order_Rpt";
string Fname = "C://" + Session["Rpt_Name"].ToString() + ".pdf";

paramField = new ParameterField();
paramField.Name = "@LPONO";
paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramDiscreteValue.Value = Session["LPO_NO"].ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);
reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@LPONO", paramDiscreteValue);

paramField = new ParameterField();
paramField.Name = "@REC_TYPE";
paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramDiscreteValue.Value = Session["ReportType1"].ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);
reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@REC_TYPE", paramDiscreteValue);
// Session["param"] = paramFields;
//Session["reportdoc"] = "~/Boreports/Print_Lpo.rpt";
CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
reportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Fname);
Session["MyFilePath"] = Fname;
```

how i will get my serverside exported file on client machine??

Answer (score 0):

You can't access server side files from the client (unless the client happens to be running on the same machine as the server).

You will need to stream the file back to the client, or save it in a shared location.

Here's an example: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rjdudley/archive/2005/03/14/2565.aspx